# Rest webservices 404 Not Found

Tags: web-services, rest

i create a rest webservice which try to access an EJB and invoke a method on.

```
@Path("mobil")
@Stateless
public class MobileRequestHandlerEjb {

@EJB
private LoginHandlingLocal loginHandling;

@GET
@Produces({"application/json"})
public BUsers login() {
    return loginHandling.login("TST","AAA");
}
```

when i try to access the service this way from my browser:

http://localhost:7001/myappname-war/webresources/mobil

Error 404 page shows up.

I'm using netbeans and when i try to test the wervice by rightclick and test resource uri, IDE popup windows shows:

"Unable to open resource url:
http://localhost:7001/myappname-war/webresources/mobil

Make sure the project has been deployed successfully and the server is running."

My application is running. So when i try to open another parts it's works fine.

could anybody please help? what is the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Why 7001 and not 8080?

Comment: because my app is running on weblogic and this is the default port. as i wrote my application another parts working fine. so if i want to access the login page like this way: http://localhost:7001/myappname-war/faces/main/login.xhtml it's working.. :)

Comment: Netbeans-->YourProject-->Right click RestfulWebServices-->Test Restful Web Services-->Locally...

Comment: nothing happened.. :(